# Error in data.frame(cholest$cholesterol, imp_reg$cholesterol) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 515, 0

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, plot

estoy intentando graficar la distribución antes y después de aplicarle imputación por regresión logística. Al aplicar el mismo código que uso para Imputación Múltiple y que por tanto sé que funciona, me salta ese error. Adjunto todo el código, mil gracias a todo aquel que pueda echar un cable!

```
install.packages("ALA", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(ALA)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)

# defino modelo y predicciones para subsample
fit <- lm(cholesterol ~ month, data = cholest)
pred <- predict(fit, newdata = ic(cholest))

# imputación alternativa utilizando MICE
imp_reg <- mice(cholest, method = "norm.predict", m=1, maxit=3, seed=1)

# Verificación del modelo de imputación empleado en cada variable
imp_reg$meth

# Dataframe con las 2 variables cholesterol de los 2 datasets
comp_chol <- data.frame(cholest$cholesterol, imp_reg$cholesterol)
comp_chol <- melt(comp_chol)
## No id variables; using all as measure variables

# Plot de densidad con las 2 variables age de los 2 datasets (no se produjeron imputaciones porque hyp no tenía NAs)
ggplot(comp_chol, aes(x=value)) +
  geom_density(aes(group=variable, colour=variable, fill=variable), alpha=0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es porque estas intentando crear 1 data frame en donde el numero de filas es distinto en las dos variables que deseas graficar

Por lo que veo quieres graficar la variable cholesterol con y sin la inputacion

en primer lugar podemos darnos cuenta que la variable de la base original tiene 68 NA

```
table(is.na(cholest$cholesterol))
```

y por otro lado los valores inputados los podemos obtener mediante:

```
valores_imp = imp_reg$imp$cholesterol
names(valores_imp) = "cholesterol"
```

que tiene exactamente 68 filas

```
dim(valores_imp)[1]
```

Para poder graficar y hacer la comparación, debiésemos juntar en un data frame
las dos variables, la de origen y la nueva que tiene los valores origen y los NA inputados

```
cholest_input = cholest %>% 
  filter(!is.na(cholesterol)) %>% 
  select(cholesterol) %>% 
  rbind(valores_imp)
```

Con esto eliminamos los NA de la base original y le pegamos los valores nuevos

Finalmente creamos una data con ambas variables y la graficamos:

```
comp_chol <-
  data.frame(
    cholesterol_sin_input = cholest$cholesterol,
    cholesterol_con_input = cholest_input$cholesterol
  )

comp_chol <- melt(comp_chol)

ggplot(comp_chol, aes(x=value)) +
  geom_density(aes(group=variable, colour=variable, fill=variable), alpha=0.1)
```

Te resultaría algo así

[image: Grafico comparativo]

Comment: Buenas tardes Bastian, quería no solo darte las gracias por responder a mi pregunta, sino por explicarlo de una manera tan clara y comprensible. Muchísimas gracias, esto era el penúltimo escollo de mi código, y esto me ha ayudado muchísimo. Espero que tengas un buen día!